# In Firefox, `a:before` has opacity overwritten by `a`

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, pseudo-element

I have a link. I'm using `:before` to put an icon in front of it. Initially, the text is invisible (`opacity: 0`) while the icon is visible (`opacity: 1`). Upon hovering, the text will become visible. I'm using opacity as opposed to visibility or display because I need it to use the transition property.

I've found that I can do this in Chrome by setting the `:before` element to `display:block` (without this, it refuses to have an opacity different from the rest of the link). Unfortunately, I've also found that even after adding this, Firefox won't let it have an opacity different from the rest of the link.

The page in which I'm using this effect can be viewed [here](http://codepen.io/wbar8417/full/mpdFs) (and here's the [codepen source](http://codepen.io/wbar8417/pen/mpdFs)), but I've boiled the problem down to its simplest form and reproduced it below.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/afdqp3nq/)

```css
a {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
a:before {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    opacity: 1;
    content: "+";
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Sample Text</a>
```

As you can see, in Chrome (I'm using v37.0 x64 for RPM Linux), the plus sign is fully opaque, while the text is partially transparent. This is the intended behavior. However, in Firefox (I'm using v31.0 x64 for RPM Linux), the entire thing is partially transparent.

I should mention that there are some stipulations to my project which limit my options here. Firstly, I cannot change the HTML, as it is all being generated from absurdly generic markdown. Secondly, I am using no images. On the upside, however, I have no need to support older browsers.

Which brower's implementation is "correct"? Is there a better way to achieve the effect I've described? Barring a more robust solution, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:before` pseudo element is actually rendered inside the element you are applying it to since it's intended as content before the content in your element.

`opacity` also get's inherited on all child elements so you will have to change your markup to actually have the element outside your div. 
Read about transparency specs on http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency

Or you could use `rgba()` to set the color of your text - ofcourse this approach works only if you are manipulating background or text color, but at least is consistent cross browsers.

The behaviour you are experiencing in Firefox *could* be a Firefox bug since the other browsers render the same as chrome (tested chrome, opera and internet explorer with same results).

```css
a {
    color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    font-size:60px;
    font-weight:bold
}
a:before {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    opacity: 1;
    content: "+";
    color:rgba(0,0,0,1);

}
```

```html
<a href="#">Sample Text</a>
```

Comment: when you say it is rendered "inside" the element, do you mean that it is a child element in the typical DOM concept of a child element? if so, is it not true that children can overwrite style which they inherited from parents by specifying them explicitly, as i've done in the example? finally, since it is working in chrome, does that mean that chrome has an incorrect implementation of the `:before` class?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow your logic is correct - however it does not apply to opacity:  "If the object is a container element, then the effect is as if the contents of the container element were blended against the current background using a mask where the value of each pixel of the mask is <alphavalue>." http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency

Comment: should that apply even after setting `display:block`? this seems to be where chrome and firefox differ.

Comment: if it helps, i'm experimenting with setting opacity on child elements in the typical DOM structure (not pseudo-classes) and finding that i can't increase a child's opacity above the parent's opacity (as you described above), even when that child is displayed as block. http://jsfiddle.net/L5tdb0qc/

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow That behaviour is ok - however it seems that display:block is the one that affects the rendering between webkit (chrome, opera and also internet explorer) and firefox, but I guess firefox is bugged here. I guess this is somehow connected to the stacking order, but ff somehow get's it wrong. A good clue is the Note text on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_and_float

Comment: it sounds to me like the bug lies with webkit, not firefox. using the element inspector, `::before` is definitely a DOM child of `a`, and shouldn't be able to increase its opacity beyond that of the `a` tag, according to the spec you linked, regardless of display type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61523/discussion-between-easwee-and-woodrow-barlow).

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow before is never a dom child - that is just how the inspector displays it for you for easier inspection. It is pseudo content which is added by your css - it never exists in the dom and can't be manipulated other than by css.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the behavior of Firefox is correct. Pseudo elements are not DOM descendants of the element, but they belong to its render tree, so the opacity of the element should apply to them, too. Although `opacity` isn't an inherited property in the terms of CSS inheritance, it applies to the element as a whole, with everything inside it that does render at all. Generated content shouldn't be exceptional, it's just a part of element's rendered content.

If elements with opacity are nested, their opacity values multiply (e.g. placing and element with `opacity:0.5` inside the container with `opacity:0.5` and transparent background will have the same visual effect as giving it `opacity:0.25`). So setting `opacity:1` to the nested element means not "restore the opacity to fully opaque", but "preserve the opacity of the container". Since `opacity` isn't inherited property in terms of CSS inheritance, contents of the element with opacity have `opacity:1` by default.

IIRC, very early experimental Mozilla implementation (pre-Firefox 0.9) allowed to 'undo' the opacity of the nested elements by specifying values more than 1, e.g. `-moz-opacity:2`, but the spec never allowed this.

The behavior of Chromium looks like a bug because it happens only for `display:block` (or `float`, which also results in block display, but surprisingly not with `position: absolute`) and only for `opacity: 1` (which is default, so omitting it has the same effect). Changing the opacity to `0.99` or adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` (popular hack that creates a 'render layer' for the element, often fixing some render bug and enabling GPU acceleration) results in the same rendering as in Firefox, which is expected result according to the spec (as far as I understand).